# How to create hoverstates with svg <use> tag

Tags: html, css, svg, css-selectors

So I recently found this [svg technique](http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/#comment-1583277) on csstricks and decided to use it in conjunction with the grunt task [grunt-svgstore](https://github.com/FWeinb/grunt-svgstore). I thought this was the perfect thing since you have access to the actual svg with css and javascript without pasting the whole svg code in the html. But I found one major problem I can't solve which is hoverstates (and similar). The problem is the following. If that's my html body (with the svg on top)

```
<body>
    <svg>
        <symbol id="arrow">
            <path ... />
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg id="icon-arrow">
        <use xlink:href="#arrow"></use>
    </svg>
</body>
```

I can access the `#icon-arrow` svg or the `#arrow` symbol but neither will give me the ability to create a hoverstate. When doing `#icon-arrow` I can get a hoverstate but I can't access the actual shape because it is not actually a child of the `#icon-arrow` so doing `#icon-arrow #arrow:hover` won't work. On the other hand directly selecting the shape doesn't work because the shape is not actually there but it's only a reference. Is it actually possible to do hoverstates using this technique? Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: what effect are you looking for , color to switch on hover, stroke, ... ? like this ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJirA

Comment: Ha! Yeah in its basic form that's pretty much it! It doesn't work with transitions though. Also is it somehow possible to select inner elements of the shape? `.icon:hover use path {}` doesn't really work.

Comment: nop you cannot select inner tags from the SVG used/linked